# VIP Technologies Professional for Amiga, a Lotus 1-2-3 clone

Tags: amiga, software

I accidentally stumbled upon a programme named **Professional** by a company named **VIP Technologies** for the Amiga computer. It seems to be a clone (a quite accurate one) of **Lotus 1-2-3**. I cannot locate any info on the net about it, apart from a classified ad in ebay; apparently the name of the software house and the product do not help.

It must be American, since it's NTSC only - runs on PAL but with 200 lines hard limit. In the back of the manual a **DITEK** company is mentioned, plus "manufactured in Canada".

Anybody knows anything about the programme or the software house? Did it sell in any decent numbers? 1-2-3 compatibility?

Regarding licensing, I suppose it was not needed, since 1-2-3 was also a clone (or relied heavily on) of VisiCalc.

Screenshots:

[image: Initial screen]

[image: main programme]

From ebay, manual:

[image: manual, front]
[image: manual, back]

Comment: Perhaps related to Ditek Software Corp,
60 West Wilmot St, Richmond Hill, ON L4B 1M6 - may also have made "Dynacadd" a 2D and 3D personal CAD package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

VIP Technologies was a company based in Santa Barbara, CA. The company president was Dave Nelson. Marketing manager Tom Nelson.

*VIP Professional* was released on the Apple IIc, IIe, IIgs, Amiga and Atari ST series, and there's a lot of information about the Atari version. On the Atari ST, it came in text-based and GEM versions. The Amiga version list price was $199.95. All versions were distributed/advertised by ISD Marketing Inc. InfoWorld articles mention an IBM PC version but I've yet to see an advert for it.

As you've found, it comprises a cell-based spreadsheet editor and various types of charts.

In this December 1985 episode of Computer Chronicles, Atari Marketing Manager Bryan Kerr uses *VIP Professional* to demonstrate the mouse-based GUI and graphics capabilities of GEM on the 520ST at 15:30. An InfoWorld article confirms why an Atari rep was demonstrating the software - Atari was in talks to distribute *VP* at some point but no deal was reached.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kX5N8lWpqLM

[image]

This advert claims that VIP Pro has 'Total Lotus 1-2-3' compatibility, which includes the file format not just the formulas, and reviews seem to confirm this.

[image]

Jon Custer's comment is correct - "VIP Professional is a trademark of DITEK INT'L"

http://www.atarimania.com/utility-atari-st-vip-professional_28354.html

https://www.atarimagazines.com/v5n1/vipproffesional.html

There's a review on page 14 of this issue of Atari Explorer. They apparently did 'a marvellous job in producing an almost exact clone of 1-2-3', although it was slower than similar applications on other (more expensive) computers.

http://www.digitpress.com/library/magazines/atari_explorer/atari_explorer_spring87.pdf

In Amiga World Nov/Dec 1986, there's a full review of the Amiga version of *VIP* you're asking about:

https://archive.org/details/amiga-world-1986-11/page/n103/mode/2up on page 102.

In an episode of The Record podcast at 6:50, an ex-employee of VIP says that VIP Technologies folded because 'they didn't pay their taxes'.

http://therecord.co/2014/03/28/john_chaffee

Comment: If anyone can find the Infoworld link about Atari distributing VIP, I'd appreciate it. I found it, then lost it!

Comment: So there is ISD Marketing, VIP Technologies, and Ditek Software all involved. I presume Ditek was the software house, and ISD and VIP were distribution?

Comment: I think VIP Technologies was the developer, Ditek might have been a publisher(?) and ISD a distributor.

Comment: Great info! The Atari ST - GEM version seems very polished. I found it on the net and ran it on Hatari emulator. It's fully windowed, yet Lotus 1-2-3's shortcuts ( slash and capital letters) work too. Interesting amalgamation. If Lotus had tried this early on Windows, Excel might not become the spreadsheet standard :)